# How do I keep Chrome Extension running on page reload by form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension for auto filling forms and their submission. The problem is that each time I click on submit button, the page reloads and the extension stops. Is there any way to keep the extension going even after form submit?

P.S. Cannot use preventDefault() as I want the form's actions to happen.
Also the extension should work for all possible forms, so I cannot edit the form and use type="button" instead of type="submit". It has to be a submit button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Since the tab is navigated to a different URL, the old page environment is completely destroyed including its content scripts so in that sense you can't keep it running. You'll have to offload some of the logic into a background script or store the state in chrome.storage.local so that the when your content script runs on the response page it would pick it up.